# More customization with the Custom App framework for chromecast receiver app?

Tags: javascript, chromecast

I am looking to implement my receiver app with use of the custom app framework. However, I am noticing the available customization options seems to be just a buffed up styled media receiver. Referring to the table here:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/customize_ui

For example, if I wanted to move the buffering image to the center of the screen, is this type of customization available with the CAF? If not, what options do I have for this type of customization?

```
body {
   --playback-logo-image: url('http://some/image.png');
}
cast-media-player {
  --theme-hue: 100;
  --buffering-image: url('http://some/Bufferimage.png'); 
}
```

Comment: Try to [add advanced features to your CAF Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/advanced#styling-the-player), or if you want to [custom UI data binding](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/advanced#custom-ui-data-binding).

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 So basically I can use the custom UI data binding and implement my own CSS styles and enable each one depending on the current state of the player? For instance if I created a pause-Button css element i can essentially listen for a user to click pause and then enable this css element.Let me know if I have the right idea.